# Check a checkbox in Gridview for particular rows using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview with checkboxes.My GridView Structure is

```
   Name      Relation      Relation Name
----------------------------------------------------
  John
----------------------------------------------------      
 checkbox     Father 
-----------------------------------------------------
                            Robert
---------------------------------------------------
 checkbox     Mother       
---------------------------------------------------
                            Jessy
--------------------------------------------------
 Tom
-----------------------------------------------------
 Checkbox    Father
------------------------------------------------------
                            Joe
-----------------------------------------------------
 checkbox    Mother
-----------------------------------------------------
                            Helen       
----------------------------------------------------
```

the question is I need to check only one checkbox near john's father or mother and tom's father or mother.If i check the john's father and when i try to check the john's mother it should display alert message to check either father or mother for john.I should be able to check one checkbox from john and one checkbox from tom..i need to do this in jquery or javascript. Please help me

Comment: can you put some code for data-binding to grid view for the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have a single selection I guess **radio button** will be the right control. You can set the radio button name different for different rows and same for a single row.

[Something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/xUPnV/)

***Code***

```
<table id="tblRelation">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            John
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Father
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="row1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Mother
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            David
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Father
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="row2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Mother
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```